# Shortest path from one $\to$ ten with a twist - Updated

Tags: formation-of-numbers

**NOTE:** *The rules have been updated to cause the nature of the puzzle to be as intended. I will upvote the answer which was given before the change, but I look for both alphabetic and math operations to be used to solve the puzzle.*

There are the kinds of puzzles where you take a number and try through math to get it to another number, or start with letters, and try to get to another word through a series of valid words... but what about a combination of the two.

**The rules:**

```
                           (15 14  5)
Starting with the letters: _ o  n  e_
```

and changing only one letter at a time **or** converting the letters to numbers, apply one mathematical operation specified below, you must follow the path of:

*one* $\to$ *two* $\to$ *three* $\to$ *four* $\to$ *five* $\to$ *six* $\to$ *seven* $\to$ *eight* $\to$ *nine* $\to$ *ten*

Each result of a letter substitution must be a valid English word. When converting to numbers, the results of the math do *not* need to be valid words when applying operations, but must be to switch back to letters (which must happen for each of the goalpoints).

**Valid math operations:**
*(all except rotation of numbers to a single characters digits)*

$+1$,$-1$,$\times2$,$\mod27$,sum the digits (14 $\to$ 5),multiply the digits (14 $\to$ 4) rotate numbers clockwise or counterclockwise (15, 14, 5 $\to$ 14, 5, 15 etc)

**Valid alphabetic operations:**

add a letter, remove a letter, rotate characters clockwise or counterclockwise.

I will allow for roughly a month if there is interest and will accept the shortest path as the answer, with upvotes for partial solutions. Good luck!

***Note:*** The switching of characters between numbers and letters does NOT count as a step, so does not penalize you.

Comment: The rotation of numbers cannot be "to a single character's digits".

Comment: ...so are the others applied to each and every character or to a single one of our choosing (or either)?

Comment: Doesn't the "change a single letter" operation make all of the maths operations redundant? (as well as the rot13 single letter)

Comment: @JaapScherphuis Yep, I think the minimum path currently is dictated by Levenshtein distance. Edit: except words must me in a dictionary...

Comment: Ok, so the restriction to dictionary words for the alphabetic operations might indeed mean that the maths operations could be used to get you out of a tricky spot, but I think that going through some longer word ladder will generally take fewer steps than the rather restrictive maths operations need to get back to a valid word.

Comment: I updated the rules to reflect what I was thinking for the puzzle (The first post was done in haste and when tired). The hope is that both operations would be relied upon to accomplish this. Many people know how to do the straight alphabetic transformation, but this is a new twist...

Comment: Updated wording to clarify what I meant by "step"... I meant each of one,two,three etc.

Answer (score 3):

***Note***: This is currently invalid due to a change in the specification, but may give an aim for people.

Using only character substitution (*now banned*), character addition, and character removal (all words are currently linked to their definition in the Oxford English Dictionary):

> **42** steps (33 intermediaries):
>
>  **one** -> [owe](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/owe) -> [we](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/we) -> [wo](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/wo) -> **two** -> [tho](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/tho) -> [the](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/the) -> [thee](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/thee) -> **three** -> [thee](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/thee) -> [the](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/the) -> [toe](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/toe) -> [foe](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/foe) -> [fou](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/fou) -> **four** -> [fou](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/fou) -> [foe](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/foe) -> [fie](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/fie) -> **five** -> [fine](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/fine) -> [sine](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/sine) -> [sin](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/sin) -> **six** -> [sin](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/sin) -> [sen](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/sen) -> [seen](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/seen) -> **seven** -> [seen](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/seen)-> [sen](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/sen) -> [sin](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/sin)-> [sign](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/sign) -> [sigh](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/sigh) -> [sight](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/sight) -> **eight** -> [sight](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/sight) -> [sigh](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/sigh) -> [sign](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/sign) -> [sin](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/sin) -> [sine](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/sine) -> **nine** -> [tine](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/tine) -> [tin](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/tin) -> **ten**

Could the lack of restriction to dictionary words for "mathematical" operations help us...?

Comment: Thank you for the initial answer. I updated the rules to reflect the desired goal of the puzzle. The idea is to use both math and alphabetic swaps to make the chain. I believe you will find that the math is now needed. This answer could serve as a jumping block though for possible word goals to shoot for in the switching to valid words.